# FMX LiveBindings CustomFormat IfThen with three results or more

Tags: database, delphi, firemonkey, firedac, livebindings

I have an FDTable with an integer column which to the user must appear as a set of different strings in a grid. Example: 0 as 'Null', 1 as 'Open', 2 as 'Closed'. Etc.

For a simple column with only two possibilities I already set the CustomFormat property of the column to `IfThen(%s = "0", 'No', 'Yes')`. This works well, but when I tried to do the same for the said column before and set CustomFormat to `IfThen(%s = "0", 'Null', IfThen(%s = "1", 'Open', 'Closed'))` it doesn't work at all (FDTable throws an unnamed exception on activating). How do I accomplish what I've explained?

Comment: It looks like there are some typos in your question (unmached quotes for example). Please edit you question to fix that. Also, "doesn't work at all" is not a clear description. Do you mean no error and no effect, just as you have done nothing? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a frequent way of solving that kind of problem is to have a table with the translation (two columns, one integer and one string) and have your SQL request do the job of translating using a join.

Comment: @fpiette I edited my question to be more specific. If I could make a concise question it would be "How can I use the CustomFormat property to format  a set of 3 integers to 3 strings the same way you can use IfThen to format a set of 2 integers to 2 strings".

Comment: Another often used technique is to add a calculated field to the table, fill it with the description in the OnCalcFields event handler and then bind that to the grid (or other control).